# "Идти вразрез"

Tags: орфография

"Идти вразрез" - "В()разрез" пишется слитно или раздельно?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае ВРАЗРЕЗ 'вопреки, резко противореча' - наречие, пишется слитно. *Вразрез* с чем. (разг.). Например: *Действовать вразрез с инструкцией; Идти вразрез*. (Грамота.ру)